# Joining Tables with optional conditions/OR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a left outer join with multiple OR conditions.

```
declare @table table (ID  char(3));
insert into @table values 
('001'), ('001'), ('002'), ('003'), ('004')

declare @join_table table (AUX_ID char(3), AUD_ID char(3));
insert into @join_table values 
('001', ''),
('002','001'),
('002','003'),
('004','007'),
('005','006')


SELECT a.ID, b.AUX_ID, b.AUD_ID
FROM @table a LEFT JOIN @join_table b
ON a.ID = b.AUX_ID
OR a.ID = b.AUD_ID
```

with this code, I get:

```
ID  AUX_ID  AUD_ID
001 001    
001 002 001
001 001    
001 002 001
002 002 001
002 002 003
003 002 003
004 004 007
```

I want a list of all the IDs, from the original table and also the matched ones from the join table.

```
ID
001
001
002
003
004
007
```

Comment: Why are you joining on AUD_ID and AUX_ID ?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: +1 for providing sample data as DDL+DML, but can you please update your question to include the desired results?

Comment: How did the `004` record fit in your critiria?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I corrected it! Sorry I was confusing myself

Comment: Yes, but you also specified not null for both left join columns, so basically you changed your left join to an inner join...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to match the first item in your condition, similar to a short-circuiting condition?

If so, try using COALESCE:

```
SELECT a.ID, b.AUX_ID, b.AUD_ID
FROM @table a LEFT JOIN @join_table b
ON a.ID = COALESCE( b.AUX_ID, b.AUD_ID, '' )
WHERE COALESCE( b.AUX_ID, b.AUD_ID, NULL ) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns all IDs if they exist in either column:

```
SELECT distinct a.ID, b1.AUX_ID, b2.AUD_ID
FROM @table a 
LEFT JOIN @join_table b1 ON a.ID = b1.AUX_ID
LEFT JOIN @join_table b2 ON a.ID = b2.AUD_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the ID's (or other fields) from @Table?
Then you could use an EXISTS in the where CLAUSE.

```
SELECT a.ID
FROM @table a
-- add joins to other tables here
WHERE EXISTS
(
  select 1
  from @join_table b
  where b.AUX_ID is not null 
    and b.AUD_ID is not null
    and a.ID in(b.AUX_ID,b.AUD_ID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update based on comments.**

Your requirement - "don't want distinct but don't want duplicates" - would be contradictory using the standard definitions of "distinct" and "duplicate".  So what we need is a definition of "duplicate" as you're using the term.

What you *seem* to be saying is that `ID` is not unique within the original `@table`, but you want a single result for each `@table` record if it matches at least one `@join_table` record.  This can be done, but I expect trouble down the line unless there's something we're not seeing.

Basically, the way the queries are currently shown, there's no way to uniquely identify a row from `@table`, or - more to the point - to tell which `@table` row was the source of a row in the joined result set.

If `@table` has additional records that form a unique key, then you can include them in the query so that `DISTINCT` doesn't treat them as duplicates.

If not, you can use `row_number()` to create a unique identifier; but this created identifier is peculiar to the query and cannot later be used to associate back to a particular row from `@table`.  That said, there are several variations, but here's one:

```
SELECT distinct a.RID, a.ID
  FROM           (select ID, row_number() over() as R_ID
                    from @table) as a
       LEFT JOIN @join_table b
              ON a.ID = b.AUX_ID
              OR a.ID = b.AUD_ID
 WHERE b.AUX_ID IS NOT NULL OR b.AUD_ID IS NOT NULL
```

or if you really want just the `ID` in the final result, wrap that in `select ID from (` ... `)`

---

**Original Reply**

So the join is working fine, but of course it replicates rows (as all joins do) when there are multiple matches.

But really the issue is you're asking for all combinations of ID when you want the distinct values of the first ID.  So:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID
  FROM @table a LEFT JOIN @join_table b
    ON a.ID = b.AUX_ID
    OR a.ID = b.AUD_ID
 WHERE b.AUX_ID IS NOT NULL OR b.AUD_ID IS NOT NULL
```

The database can only give you what you want if you ask for what you want.

Comment: Hi @Mark, sorry i wasn't clear, I don't want to get distinct, but I don't want duplicate data either. I want the number of records to be exactly the same as in the main table. You think it's possible to do this?

Comment: Do I think it's possible?  Maybe. Likely to end well?  ...  Not really.  But best of luck; I've updated with some idea of how.